# Placehold for variable names in python2

Tags: python

In python2, if I want to print something like:

```
print 'enrollment:' + str(len(enrollment))
print 'submissions:' + str(len(submissions))
```

I need to output the title and the length ; tried to format:

```
print ('%d:' + str(len('%d'))) %enrollment
```

which gives me:

> "TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict"

BTW both "enrollment" and "submissions" are variables storing dictionary

Is there a way to apply a placeholder for both string and the variable name?

Comment: what's the value of enrollment ?

Comment: `str(len('%d'))` is going to become `'2'`

Comment: Could you clarify the output you require from your final `print`?  Maybe:  `print 'enrollment: %d' % len(enrollment)`   or print '%s: %d' % ('enrolment', len(enrollment))`?

Comment: if you're trying to print the number of keys in your dictionaries just do `len(yourdict.keys())` instead of `len(yourdict)`

Comment: enrollment is a dict,consider it a mail list stores names and addresses

Comment: @kessi: `len(yourdict)` is the same as `len(yourdict.keys())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are perhaps looking for something like the following:

```
>>> enrollment = {'a':1,'b':2}
>>> submissions = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> for x in ['enrollment','submissions']:
...     print('%s: '+str(len(eval(x)))) % x
...
enrollment: 2
submissions: 3
```

Note that here the dictionary for a given iteration `x` is actually the *name* of the dictionary as a string, which is `eval`ed to get the dictionary for counting

It should also be noted that using `eval` is generally frowned upon - if the string passed into this function is valid python code, it will get executed - so if the string passed in comes from e.g. user input, the user could potentially run code you don't want to be run. In a case like this where the strings are hard-coded in your own code, it should be fine though.

Comment: If you are going to use `eval` (which is generally frowned upon), then `print '%s: %d' % (x, len(eval(x)))` might be simpler.

Comment: I realise `eval` is frowned upon, but in this context, the input is clearly defined, and I can't see any other way of doing what the OP is asking (or at least what I think they are asking). Good point though

Comment: Thanks~that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you need a name to be associated permanently with an object then you should use a dictionary, not try to back-trace from the object back to a variable name.  It requires some design thought, but is worth doing if you really need that association, for example:

```
coll = {'enrollment' : {'k1':'v1','k2':'v2', 'k3':None},
        'submissions': {...}}

for key, val in coll.items():
    print '%s: %d' % (key, len(val))
```

This avoids `eval`, which is generally frowned upon:  [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)